# beforeShowDay disables minDate in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, mindate

I'm using two jQuery datepickers, with disabled dates based on a generated array. When I put the $("#date") datepickers after the $('input') one, that works fine. However, I also need a mindate set to today, and a maxDate set to 1 year after that; it works when the order is the other way around. How can I manage to make them both work?

```
$(function() {
    var array=[]; //disabled dates for the beforeShowDay go here

    $('input').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [$.inArray(string, array) == -1];
      }
    });

    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      minDate: new Date(),
      maxDate: '+1y',
      onSelect: function(date){

        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
        $("#date1").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
        $("#date1").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+1y' );
      }
    });

    $("#date1").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    });
  });
```

Comment: please add working jsfiddle

Comment: I have to agree with @TechBreak: it would be easier to help you when you add a JSFiddle to demonstrate your problem. At least you should show the HTML you are using.

Comment: I can't get either datepicker to work on jsfiddle,  as for the html, it's pretty much just an <input id="date"> and <input id="date1">. The problem doesn't seem to lie within the html. If I commentate the whole of the $('input').datepicker() the other two work just as I want them to, if I commentate the other two, the $('input').datepicker() greys out the dates I want it to grey out. I'm wondering if there's something in the javascript code that might be conflicting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not try to apply two selectors ('input' and '#date') on the same DOM element because the second can override what the first configured. If you would like that both datepickers share the same `beforeShowDay` function you can declare it once and assign it to each datepicker.

It is not totally clear to me what you want to achieve. But maybe the following approach with a common `beforeShowDay` function could help. In any case the example below will show you how to insert a JSFiddle including datepicker into your question to clarify what you want.

```js
$(function() {
    var array=['2016-12-08']; //disabled dates for the beforeShowDay go here
    var beforeShowDay = function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [$.inArray(string, array) == -1];
      };

    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: beforeShowDay,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      minDate: new Date(),
      maxDate: '+1y',
      onSelect: function(date){
        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
        $("#date1").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
        $("#date1").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+1y' );
      }
    });

    $("#date1").datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: beforeShowDay,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="date">
<input id="date1">
```

Comment: This was exactly what was wrong with it, thanks a lot!